# How to set a Button's width to fix the remaining screen size inside a Linear Layout if there are 2 Buttons (1 with spcified width)

Tags: android, xml

I have an horizontal `LinearLayout` which contains 2 `Buttons`, one Button has a specified width (57dp) and the other one should fill the remaining screen size.
I tried like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fold_action"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/order_button"
            android:text="test" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/like_action"
            android:layout_width="57dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:background="@drawable/wish_off" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

But this way the `Button` that should fill the remaining part of the screen gets the same width as the `LinearLayout` so the `Buttons` goes off screen. Is there a way to do it in xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set layout_width to 0dp and layout_weight to 1